# Spring Integration XPathMessageSplitter + HeadEnricher

Tags: xpath, spring-integration, header-enricher

I am currently using Spring-Integration with JavaConfig and using IntegrationFlows. I am reading in a xml-file which looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<languages>
    <language name='de'>
        <translations>
            <translation key='Aktien' value='Aktien'/>
            <translation key='Andere' value='Andere'/>
        </translation>
    </language>
    <language name='en'>
        <translations>
            <translation key='Aktien' value='Stock'/>
            <translation key='Andere' value='Others'/>
        </translation>
    </language>
</languages>
```

My Configuration currently looks like:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow translationFileReadingFlow() throws IOException {
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from(pollableFileSource(), e -> e.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(MAX_VALUE)))
            .split(translationFileSplitter())
            .channel("processFileChannel")
            .logAndReply();
}

@Bean
@SubscribeMapping(value = "processFileChannel")
public IntegrationFlow applicationShutDown() {
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from("processFileChannel")
            .resequence()
            .handle(new ShutdownService())
            .get();
}

private AbstractMessageSplitter translationFileSplitter() {
    XPathMessageSplitter splitter = new XPathMessageSplitter("/languages/*");
    return splitter; 
}
```

I would like to split the xml by language (what works so far), BUT I would like to add also the information of the languages into the header of the message. The information are in the xml `<language name='de'>`. Can I solve it with the `XPathMessageSplitter` directly or do I need the `XPathHeaderEnricher`, if yes how would it work?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not to the subject:

I'm not sure that:

```
@Bean
@SubscribeMapping(value = "processFileChannel")
public IntegrationFlow applicationShutDown() {
```

Is correct code. The `@SubscribeMapping` is for a POJO-based method mapping. You definitely can't map an `IntegrationFlow`. If you still need to call a flow from such a `@SubscribeMapping`, you need to consider to introduce a `@MessagingGateway` interface for starting the flow and calling from that POJO-method.

You indeed cannot add headers via splitter. It is just not its responsibility.

If you need to populate a header from an XML in the `payload`, you definitely need to take a look into `XPathHeaderEnricher`. In your case it could be like this:

```
@Bean
public XPathHeaderEnricher xPathHeaderEnricher() {
    Map<String, XPathExpressionEvaluatingHeaderValueMessageProcessor> expressionMap =
            Collections.singletonMap("language",
                    new XPathExpressionEvaluatingHeaderValueMessageProcessor("/language/@name"));
    return new XPathHeaderEnricher(expressionMap);
}
```

and use after that mentioned `.split()`:

```
.split(translationFileSplitter())
.handle(xPathHeaderEnricher())
```

There is another way via SpEL, though: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.2.0.RELEASE/reference/html/spel.html#spel-functions

```
.enrichHeaders((headers) -> 
             headers.headerExpression("language", "#xpath(payload, '/language/@name')"))
```

Comment: Hi Artem, thank you very much for your response. It is my first time using spring integration with JavaConfig (before always used xml). It is a kind of different somehow, but I guess it is worth to switch. The solution with `.enrichHeaders(...)` I like :-) Thanks for the off topic hint. It is just a small tool and I just started.